# flash negative color, i want to change color of negative value from black to red, and positive in green

Tags: javascript, php

i have this format table of price and want to display in table with flash color anyhelp with this
what to do ?
decode encode fetch?
i have this format table of price and want to display in table with flash color anyhelp with this
what to do ?
decode encode fetch?

```
<?php
$bidRateUNI = 10 ;
$UNIUSDBUY = 22;  
$UNIUSDSELL = 33;
$BUY1UNI = $bidRateUNI - $UNIUSDBUY;
$BUY2UNI = $bidRateUNI - $UNIUSDSELL;
$SELL1UNI = $UNIUSDBUY - $bidRateUNI;
$SELL2UNI = $UNIUSDSELL - $bidRateUNI;

?>
<html>
<body>

<title>untitled</title>
<style>
    .negative { color : red; }
    .positive { color : green; }
</style>
<?php
echo '<table>
   <tr>
        <td class="plusmin">$SELL2UNI</td>
        <td class="plusmin">$SELL1UNI</td>
        <td>$9,500</td>
        <td class="plusmin">$BUY2UNI</td>
        <td class="plusmin">$BUY1UNI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="plusmin">$53.12</td>
        <td class="plusmin">+2.5%</td>
        <td>£110,000</td>
        <td class="plusmin">$10,000</td>
        <td class="plusmin">+15.57%</td>
    </tr>
</table>';
?>

<script>
function MakePosNeg() {
  var TDs = document.querySelectorAll('.plusmin');

  for (var i = 0; i < TDs.length; i++) {
    var temp = TDs[i];
    if (temp.firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) {temp.className = "negative";}
    else {temp.className = "positive";}
  }
}
onload = MakePosNeg()
</script>
</body>
</html>

**; help with some good info** 
;help with some good info
';help with some good info

**; help with some good info** 
;help with some good info
';help with some good info
```

Comment: What are you trying to colour? The whole row? An individual cell?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. What do you want to be coloured? The column? The row? The cell?

Are you colouring the PHP output?

However, the simplest method would be to use the ternary operator in PHP rather than using javascript. A [ternary operator](https://www.codementor.io/@sayantinideb/ternary-operator-in-php-how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator-x0ubd3po6) is essentially a short-hand if/else statement. Here is an example (based on the assumption you want the font of the PHP code coloured).

`echo "<td style='color: " . $BUY1UNI < 0 ? 'red' : 'green' . "'>" . number_format($BUY1UNI, 3) . "</td>";`

Comment: respose .. " . number_format($BUY1UNI, 3) ""; ?>

Comment: Your html is not valid. You have opening <td> tags, but no closing tags.

Comment: i ve corect , .. but dont work

Comment: You still have invalid markup and you have PHP syntax errors. I've corrected, but I have to wait for someone to "approve" the edit in your question. It would be helpful if we knew what you wanted to colour.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with your code. you don't need javascript for that as @jeff Vdovjak and you have also opened php tags unnecessarily which makes confusion. I guess following code will help you

```
<?php

$bidRateUNI = 10 ;
$UNIUSDBUY = 22;
$UNIUSDSELL = 33;
$BUY1UNI = $bidRateUNI - $UNIUSDBUY;
$BUY2UNI = $bidRateUNI - $UNIUSDSELL;
$SELL1UNI = $UNIUSDBUY - $bidRateUNI;
$SELL2UNI = $UNIUSDSELL - $bidRateUNI;
?>
<html>
<body>

<title>untitled</title>

<table>
   
        <td class="plusmin" style='color:<?php if($SELL2UNI<0){echo"red";}else{ echo"green";}?>'><?php echo $SELL2UNI?></td>
        <td class="plusmin" style='color:<?php if($SELL1UNI<0){echo"red";}else{ echo"green";}?>'><?php echo $SELL1UNI?></td>
        <td>$9,500</td>
        <td class="plusmin" style='color:<?php if($BUY2UNI<0){echo"red";}else{ echo"green";}?>'><?php echo $BUY2UNI?></td>
        <td class="plusmin" style='color:<?php if($BUY1UNI<0){echo"red";}else{ echo"green";}?>'><?php echo $BUY1UNI?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="plusmin">$53.12</td>
        <td class="plusmin">+2.5%</td>
        <td>£110,000</td>
        <td class="plusmin">$10,000</td>
        <td class="plusmin">+15.57%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```